# Forces in conical pendulum

Tags: rotational-kinematics

In case of motion of a conical pendulum,why is $T\cos \theta=mg$ where $T$ is the tension of the spring and $m$ is the mass of the particle and $\theta$ the angle between the string and vertical?

Comment: Duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103771, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/607904, etc

Answer (score 1):

it comes from equilibrium between gravitation on the object (particle) and the tension in the spring (springs pretty much don't react with orthogonal forces)

Answer (score 1):

The particle is moving in a horizontal circle, so it is not in horizontal equilibrium. It is, however, in vertical equilibrium. So the vertical component of the string’s tension, which is $T\cos \theta$, must equal the particle’s mass, which is $mg$.